Azure table storage SAS generation using string to sign in c#
I need to generate SAS token for azure table storage using stringToSign method as mentioned in the documentstext. But i am not able to generate valid sas. when i use the generated sas its throwing the error "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature"
I tried the following method its always sas generated token "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature"
        private static string GenerateTableSasToken(string storageAccountName, string tableName)
        {
            string start = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
            string expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

            string stringToSign = $"r\n"+
                           $"{start}\n"+
                           $"{expiry}\n" +
                           $"/table/{storageAccountName}/{tableName}\n"+ 
                           "\n"+
                           "\n"+
                           "\n"+
                           $"2019-02-02\n" +
                           $"\n"+
                           $"\n"+
                           $"\n"+
                           $"\n";

            Console.WriteLine(stringToSign);

            string signature = CreateHMACSHA256Signature(stringToSign, storageAccountKey);

            return $"https://{storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/{tableName}(PartitionKey='Failed',RowKey='207b71')" +
                $"?sv=2019-02-02&tn=logging&st={start}&se={expiry}&sp=r&sig={Uri.EscapeDataString(signature)}";
        }

        private static string CreateHMACSHA256Signature(string stringToSign, string storageAccountKey)
        {
            byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(storageAccountKey);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
            {
                byte[] dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }
        }


I believe the reason you are getting error is because you have an extra new line character in your stringToSign.
Please try by using the following:
string stringToSign = $"r\n"+
                $"{start}\n"+
                $"{expiry}\n" +
                $"/table/{storageAccountName}/{tableName}\n"+ 
                "\n"+
                "\n"+
                "\n"+
                $"2019-02-02\n" +
                $"\n"+
                $"\n"+
                $"\n"+
                $"";

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#version-2015-04-05-and-later
StringToSign = signedPermissions + "\n" +  
               signedStart + "\n" +  
               signedExpiry + "\n" +  
               canonicalizedResource + "\n" +  
               signedIdentifier + "\n" +  
               signedIP + "\n" +  
               signedProtocol + "\n" +  
               signedVersion + "\n" +  
               startingPartitionKey + "\n"  
               startingRowKey + "\n"  
               endingPartitionKey + "\n"  
               endingRowKey

